# Mongo query based on count and if count is same then alphabetically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a coupons collections and I am trying to group all the coupons based on the code. After that I want to sort them on the basis of the count. Till this the query works fine. But after this if the count is same for coupon codes then it should sort them on the basis of another key. Here I am trying to sort it on the basis of the coupon code. But every time I run the query the order is not same and it is not being sorted properly on the basis of coupon code. I am attaching the mongoose query

```
const coupons = await Coupons.aggregate([
  { $match: couponFilter },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$code",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1, code: 1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit },
  { $project: { code: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0 } },
]);
```

Normally it should work fine but it does not work correctly. Each time I run this query it returns me the items in different order. Although, the items are sorted correctly on the basis of count but when some coupons have same count they are not sorted properly on the basis if coupon code.

Not able to attach the returned data as text so attaching it as image. These are the screenshots of the data returned when I executed the query 3 times and each time the order of coupon codes with same number of count is different.

[image: Result after running query the first time]

[image: Result after running query the second time]

[image: Result after running query the third time]

Answer (score 0):

The `$sort` stage is invalid as the field `code` is not included in the `$group`. The field `code` does not exist on the documents after the `$group` stage. Therefore, only the first half of the sort condition works.

Updated pipeline with changes in the `$sort` stage:

```
const coupons = await Coupons.aggregate([
  { $match: couponFilter },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$code",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1, _id: 1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit },
  { $project: { code: "$_id", count: 1, _id: 0 } },
]);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping with this, however I actually was looking through the code and got this mistake and it works but all the coupon codes that are in lowercase are returned at the end of list and not at their respective location according to the sorting. Any ideas about this.

Comment: Lowercase characters will appear after uppercase characters after sorting. One way to fix this would be to add a field to the group that contains the code in uppercase (use the $toUpper operator. Then use this field in sort in place of _id

Answer (score 0):

After going through mongo docs this is the final query that solved my issue

```
const coupons = await Coupons.aggregate([
  { $match: couponFilter },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$code",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      code: "$_id",
      count: 1,
      _id: 0,
      lowerCode: { $toLower: "$_id" },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1, lowerCode: 1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit },
]);
```